# Binary read jpeg and store it in SQL Server db

Tags: vb.net

I have a jpeg file in my C drive from my vb.net application I want to binary read it and store it in SQL server.
How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can read a file into a byte array by calling [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx).

You can then put the byte array into SQL Server using a [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

For example:

```
Using command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO sometable VALUES(@image)", connection)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("image", File.ReadAllBytes(path))
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks sLaks. One question. the image is not in my C drive it is in a location on the server how can I read it like 
 My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes _
("C:/Documents and Settings/selfportrait.jpg")
This is the location of the files
Server.MapPath("images\Signatures\") & Session("NetworkID").ToString() & ".jpeg")

Comment: As long as it's on a local disk, you can still read it.  If it was uploaded by the user, you can also get a byte array by reading `Request.Files[0].InputStream` or the `FileBytes` property of the `FileUpload` control.